# Error When Add options to an HTML select box with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

this is my error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null
```

And my javascript function:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     function appendlistbox(){
          var select = document.getElementById("listboxstock");
          select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("myobject", "index");
     }
</script>
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="btnaddstock" class="btn btn-default" onclick="appendlistbox()">Tambahkan Bahan</button>

<label>Bahan Yang Dibutuhkan :</label>
<select name="listboxstock" size="5" class="form-control">
</select>
```

I dont have any idea about the error...

Comment: `name` is not the same thing as `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the "name" attribute `listboxstock` to your select control, but you are not assigning the "id" attribute. And since you are using `document.getElementById`, your element cannot be found (and thus the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null` error. Either assign the id, or use `getElementsByName`:

By name:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     function appendlistbox(){
          var select = document.getElementsByName("listboxstock")[0];
          select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("myobject", "index");
     }
</script>

<button type="button" id="btnaddstock" class="btn btn-default" onclick="appendlistbox()">Tambahkan Bahan</button>

<label>Bahan Yang Dibutuhkan :</label>
<select name="listboxstock" size="5" class="form-control">
</select>
```

By Id:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
     function appendlistbox(){
          var select = document.getElementById("listboxstock");
          select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("myobject", "index");
     }
</script>

<button type="button" id="btnaddstock" class="btn btn-default" onclick="appendlistbox()">Tambahkan Bahan</button>

<label>Bahan Yang Dibutuhkan :</label>
<select id="listboxstock" name="listboxstock" size="5" class="form-control">
</select>
```

Comment: No problem. Best of luck on your project.

Answer (score 1):

You should access `select` by name property, using `document.getElementsByName` method.

`document.getElementsByName` return a `NodeList`, so you have to access your select using its index: `var select = document.getElementsByName("listboxstock")[0];`

Final solution.

```js
function appendlistbox(){
          var select = document.getElementsByName("listboxstock")[0];
          select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("myobject", "index");
     }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btnaddstock" class="btn btn-default" onclick="appendlistbox()">Tambahkan Bahan</button>

<label>Bahan Yang Dibutuhkan :</label>
<select name="listboxstock" size="5" class="form-control">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
var select = document.getElementById("listboxstock");
```

The select does not have the id "listboxstock" (that is the "name" attribute, not the id). So, you could change it to:

```
<select name="listboxstock" id="listboxstock" size="5" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your select tag needs the property `id`

```
select name="listboxstock" id="listboxstock" size="5" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="listboxstock" size="5" class="form-control"></select>

replace above line with the following line 

<select id="listboxstock" size="5" class="form-control"></select>
```